# Function as variable of integration

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to use a function as variable of integration for example in evaluating the integral over:

e^(cos(x))f(sin(x))dcos(x)

in which f(x) is an arbitrary function.

How can I change the variable of integration such that I integrate over dcos(x), instead of dx (as is default)?

**EDIT:**

When evaluating an integral such as a*x+b, one can evaluate it in the following way:

```
  def f(x,a,b):
    return a*x+b

  print quadrature(f,0,1,args=(2,3))
```

In this example the variable of integration is dx, but now I want to change the variable of integration to a function, such as x**2 (I know this can be solved analytically, but I want to apply it so a function that is not analytically solvable.), or cos(x).

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and post some specific details about the issue...

Comment: I just don't understand a single word of your question. Not everyone here has a maths degree you know, some of us are just programmers...

Comment: Sorry, I've changed it into a more understandable language. But I think that the question will be answered by someone who at least understands the first part, as it is first year university calculus.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a purely mathematical concept. An appropriate solution could be found on mathematics.stackexchange.com

Comment: It is not a mathematical question, purely on how to implement this issue, using Scipy or Numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking how to make numpy/scipy change integration variables for you. This in general requires symbolic computation (in your example: you need to use the relation between sine and cosine), and scipy does not have that.

Your best bet is to work out the transformation of variables by paper-and-pencil, write down the resulting integral, and use scipy to evaluate that.

If you look for symbolic computation tools in python land, have a look at `sympy`.

EDIT: of course, you could always sample your functions on a mesh of `x`, use interpolation to construct an implicit function, and integrate that [in your example: sample `f(x)` and `cos(x)` on a mesh of `x`, interpolate `f` vs `x` and `x` vs `cos(x)`]. Maybe your specific problem is such that it's actually worth it, so YMMV.

Comment: I am not looking for a symbolic computation, because it doesn't exist for this particular problem, so working it out by hand also won't be possible.

Comment: this does not change the answer to the question of whether scipy can change integration variables for you: it can't.

Comment: It might not be directly possible, but this problem must be numerically solvable, it's been done in literature many times, but unfortunately they never specify their methods.

Comment: See my edited answer. It seems to me you'd hardly get any more specific answer given the level of detail and amount of effort in the question.